# Can't get URL to resolve...htaccess, mod_rewrite, wordpress issue

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm having an issue with a rewrite.

I have a Wordpress install in my /blog directory, but I want the Wordpress Pages to appear outside of the blog directory.

So, in my root .htaccess I added a line:  (The first three lines were already there for redirecting everything to "www"

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^tooboss.com$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ "http\:\/\/www\.tooboss\.com/$1" [R=301,L]

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ "/blog/$1" [L]
```

I then changed the display URL within Wordpress to my root URL, and altered the permalink structure to prepend "/blog/" so it appeared my posts were still in the blog directory.

Everything works fine, but I can't get www.tooboss.com/blog to redirect to www.tooboss.com.  Instead, it throws a 404.

Any ideas?

For reference, here's the blog directory's .htaccess file"

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /blog/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /blog/index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

Am I missing something obvious?  I feel like it's getting caught between the 2 htaccess files but I'm not sure what to do to fix it.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Wouldn't this rule:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ "/blog/$1" [L]
```

cause `www.tooboss.com/blog` to get sent to `www.tooboss.com/blog/blog`?

I think you want:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !^/blog/$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ "/blog/$1" [L]
```

I'm kind of new to .htaccess myself so I might be off base here.

Comment: That code has the same issue.

I need www.tooboss.com/* to get rewritten to www.tooboss.com/blog/* because that's the directory my blog resides in.  In the case of www.tooboss.com/blog[/] though, I want a 301 to www.tooboss.com

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

In response to your comment to seth's answer, try this:

```
RewriteRule ^/blog/?$ / [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /blog/$1 [L]
```

Answer (score 0):

[I figured it out](http://www.tooboss.com/blog/2009/07/moving-wordpress-to-the-root-directory/)  Very annoying issue.  I was able to solve the issue without moving my blog to a different named directory, but it required altering the Wordpress PHP which I didn't want to do.  If Wordpress was built to handle static links in the Permalink structure I wouldn't have needed to move the install